# IPTables Rules Order

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables

I am trying to implement IPTables rules for traffic on port 443. I want to allow NEW connections up until they reach a rate limit, then drop them and log the dropped packets (I'll add rate limiting to the logging later). However, with the rules I have, my logging rule gets called with every NEW connection. I don't want to make a log entry unless the rate limit has already been reached.

Regardless of the amount of google searching I do, I can't seem to figure out this extremely basic question. I *believe* I understand that an ACCEPT rule will stop any subsequent rules from being called. But placing my logging rule either before or after the ACCEPT rule does not make any difference - the connection is still logged.

iptables -L -v -n is as follows for the INPUT chain:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 2 packets, 88 bytes)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW limit: avg 50/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW LOG flags 7 level 7 prefix "IPTables-50/m-Dropped: "
    9   612 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the the `-m limit` module to achieve this.

> `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 443 -m limit --limit 10/min -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`
>
> `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-443-Dropped: " --log-level 4`
>
> `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j DROP`

- The first line will accept the packet until they reach the rate of 10 per minute.
- The second line will match and log packets that goes above the 10 per minute.
- The third line will match and drop the same packets as the second rule.

I just tried it with ICMP packets, and I don't know if you really want to use that method : It's a rate.
Maybe you'd better be off by using the `-m connlimit` module, described in the manpage as:

> Allows you to restrict the number of parallel connections to a server per client IP address (or client address block).

Hope this helps.